# Gradle project property latest value is not picked up in doLast block

Tags: build.gradle

```
I have a problem picking up the right parameter values in the doLast method in my customer task

Example 

  I have a task loadfile as below

   

    task loadFile(type: JavaExec)
    
     {
                systemProperties = System.properties
                group = "Execution"
                main = "configurations.git.StreamYamlGitModule"
                classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
        jvmArgs = [
                "-DENV_NAME=${System.getProperty("env")}",
                ]
        }
        
        doLast {
            println (“Properites ${project.property(‘name’)}”)
        }
```

Task run java class and populate values into gradle.properties file

```
 gradle.properites 
   Name = test
   Strategy = abc
```

The problem I have is the below code doesn’t populate the latest value that is loaded into gradle.properties file for name property. It always picking up the old value (which is before the task run. Example task runs and populates the value “stage” in to properties file, but it prints old value which is “test”)

Code section which expected to print the latest value
doLast {

```
    println (“Properites ${project.property(‘name’)}”)
            }
    

Any idea how can I get the latest value printed ? appreciate your help
```